# Is it really impossible to develop Windows Store apps on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64

I am still using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. I want to learn how to develop Windows Store apps on this machine. According to the Microsoft site, Visual Studio Express for Windows can only be installed on Windows 8.1. Is it really impossible to develop Windows Store apps on Windows 7?

For example, can just we download and install the required API?

Comment: yep. those apis don't exist so you can't debug or run the apps. you could get a license of windows 8.1 and run it in a vm.

Comment: Those apps simply do not exist for Win7...

Comment: Yes. If Microsoft says you need Windows 8.1 to install it, you need Windows 8.1 to install it. You also can't run or test or debug the apps on an earlier version of Windows.

Comment: If it was already clearly stated on Visual Studio page that the product only runs on 8.1 why bother asking here?

Comment: User already found the answer on Visual Studio site and asks the same thing here hoping in a different answer.

Comment: @MatteoMosca: I thought there will be a nice trick to make it possible. Because I know you are programmers here. :-) As a result, I can save my money just for this.

Comment: Yeah we are programmers and as such we don't do "nice tricks". If you do this job the 1st thing you must learn is that you play by the rules. If a technology has its rules and limitations you either follow them or choose something different. You can't bend a software to have it do something it was not designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not impossible to install the Visual Studio on the pc, although that would require you take apart the setup and do things manually, however even if you do the install will be broken and would crash more often than not, so much that it becomes pretty much unusable. So do as the other users have told you and install Windows 8.1 on a VM. If the licensing is a problem you can download a 90 day trail version from the TechNet Evaluation Center.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because Win7 is not designed for making and running apps at all, the actual app-user-interface was introduced in windows 8. 
Edit: even if it would be possible to develop apps on Win7 there is no store for it.